# Looping through a column in R

Tags: r, statistics, loops

I am using the `R's stats` package and would like to loop through `column[x]` in `all the rows of a dataframe`, operate on the data in `each cell` in the column with a function and pass the result to a new column (with the `calculated result` in the `new column` aligned with the data in `column[x]`)

I've got two problems:

1. I can't get it to work
2. looping seems to be discouraged in the `R articles` I've read.  Is there an alternative approach and if not, does anyone have an example of how to carry out the loop?

Comment: Looping is not necessarily discouraged. Get it working first, and only then think about getting if faster.

Comment: Can you give us some more details? Like an example problem you're working with?

Answer (score 16):

Without any examples, it's hard to know how to respond.  The basic case of what you're describing, however, is this:

```
#Just a very simple data frame
dat <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3))
#Compute the squared value of each value in x
dat$y <- dat$x^2
#See the resultant data.frame, now with column y
dat
```

When you tell R to square a vector (or vector-like structure, like dat$x), it knows to square each value separately.  You don't need to explicitly loop over those values most of the time - although, as Dirk notes, you should only worry about optimizing your loops if they are causing you problems.  That said, I certainly prefer reading and writing

```
dat$y <- dat$x^2
```

to:

```
for(i in 1:length(dat$x)){
  dat$y[i] <- dat$x[i]^2
}
```

... where possible.

Comment: Thanks.  I can get arithmetic working OK. I'm not able to pass the contents of a dataframe to a function. Here's the problem.  Here's the top of the frame (called data) with headings "compound" and "SMILES" (smiles are a text representation of a molecule)

Compound_ID    SMILES
12345          c1cccccc1

I want to use the function parse.smiles() to do read in the smiles and output a molecule. If I do it on one molecule its OK (junk <- "c1ccccc1", parse.smiles(junk)
If I do 
sp <- get.smiles.parser()
junk <- sapply(data$smiles, parse.smiles, parser = sp)

it can't interpret smiles

Comment: Okay.  Sorry, wasn't quite sure where you were in R, so I thought I'd just throw the basic case out there.  "unknown" might have it - but if not, your best bet is to post a little sample data set and the function.  Kind of hard to grasp what's going wrong from a description, and I, at least, can't get any *apply functions right without experimentation.

Answer (score 1):

if parse.smiles() is a function you want to apply to all the entry of a vector "vec", then you can use:

```
lapply(1:length(vec),parse.smiles(vec[i]))
```

Comment: Thanks everyone.  The column I was interested in had been read in as a factor.  I had to be explicitly tell the function to read in the contents as characters and I had not realised this until pointed out.  It's now working.
(and apologies for garbled comment above - It was formatted with returns which disappeared when posted)

Answer (score 1):

The only reason looping is discouraged is that it is slow.  R is designed to work on vectors at a time and has lots of functions to accomplish this.  The whole apply family, as well as functions like Vectorize to help out.  So the idiom is that if your using for loops you're not thinking in R, but sometimes for loops really are just appropriate.

To do this in the R way of thinking, Vectorize your function, if it is not already vectorized (see the Vectorize function)  then call that function with the entire column as an argument and assign that to the new column.

```
f<-Vectorize(function(x,...),'x')
data$newcolumn<-f(data[,1])
```

The apply family (apply, sapply, lapply, mapply, tapply) are also alternatives.  Most native R functions are already vectorized, but be careful when passing extra arguments that are supposed to be interpreted as vectors.